# Flutter navigation with animation don't work

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

the animation works only when I make a black but the previous page but when I push to the next page it does not work. Please what to do?

i'm using flutter 3.10.0

Here is my code

```
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(
                        pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) =>
                            const Register(),
                        transitionsBuilder:
                            (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                          const begin = Offset(-1.0, 0.0);
                          const end = Offset.zero;
                          const curve = Curves.ease;
                          var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end)
                              .chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));
                          return SlideTransition(
                              position: animation.drive(tween), child: child);
                        },
                      ))
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      "Register now",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```